# Sprintf floating point number behaviour change from Ruby 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: ruby

With Ruby 2.3.7,

```
'%.2g' % 1.05
```

returns "1.1"

But with Ruby 2.4.0

```
'%.2g' % 1.05
```

returns "1.0"

Why is this behaviour different?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.4 the default strategy of `Float#round` was changed to [Gaussian rounding](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12958).

Comment: It appears it was reverted though https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12958#note-18

Answer (score 0):

"This was an early effort by Nobu to handle cases where floating point numbers rounded inconsistently with Kernel#sprintf in ruby-2.3.3"

https://blog.heroku.com/ruby-2-4-features-hashes-integers-rounding#actual-rounding-changes